# Index of coffeescript .each loop

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, arguments, each

How can I get the index of a CoffeeScript .each loop? I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find a solid answer. I know how I can do this with vanilla jQuery, but I can't figure out how to add the index argument to function() in CoffeeScript.

here is my code currently:

```
video_list_element = $('#video-list li')

video_list_element.each ->
    video_list_element.delay(100).animate({
        "top": "0"
}, 2000)
```

I'm trying to multiply the value inside of .delay() by the index of the .each loop

Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!!!

Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation for the jQuery .each() function is found here:
http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
video_list_element = $('#video-list li')
video_list_element.each (index, element) ->
  element.delay(100 * index).animate "top": "0", 2000
```

In general (sans-jQuery), the way to get the index in a coffeescript for loop is:

```
array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
for value, index in array
  console.log index, value
```

Gives:

```
0 item1
1 item2
2 item3
```

Comment: How can I do this if I want to loop through all the, for example, "p" tags with the selector $('p') and animate each "p" tag using the index to multiply the speed each iteration?

Comment: I think you meant to say `for value, index in array`; `of` is for looping over object properties, `in` is for arrays.

Comment: Either will work - `of` will require `index, value` and `in` will require `value, index`. So they do the same thing with the parameters reversed.

Regardless, I updated the answer.